# Is there any way to get the real path storing picture captured by Android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I found some Android OEM store the picture captured by android system camera(developed by OEM) in **DCIM** folder, but others in **DCIM/Camera**.

So, is there any way to get the real path storing picture captured by Android camera?

Comment: Are you taking the photo yourself ?

Comment: @Eefret what's the photo yourself mean?

Comment: "I found some Android OEM store the picture captured by android camera in DCIM folder, but others in DCIM/Camera" -- no, they don't. Camera *apps* may store photos in either of those locations, or anywhere else. OEMs might write or choose a camera app to pre-install, and users can install other camera apps from the Play Store and elsewhere.

Comment: "is there any way to get the real path storing picture captured by Android camera?" -- as suggested by Eefret, you need to explain what "Android camera" you mean. Are you writing the camera app? Are you integrating with a camera app (e.g., `ACTION_CAPTURE_IMAGE`)? Are you attempting to spy on the behavior of other camera apps not related to you?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, "android camera" is  puzzling. Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question. I want to know the camera app developed by OEM itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know the camera app developed by OEM itself.

Short of taking hostages and demanding that OEMs hand over this information, you have no means of getting it. After all:

- You have no good way of knowing what camera app was pre-installed on the device, or even if there was one
- You have no way at all of knowing whether the OEM wrote that camera app, rather than licensed it from some third party
- You have no way of knowing where that camera app will store images, because the app could store images anywhere, possibly via user-supplied configuration data (e.g., "let's link the camera to your Dropbox account!")
- You do not even know if the camera will store images in a location that you can access (e.g., camera apps could write to removable media on Android 4.4+, which your app cannot access)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you want (or if you even want an answer?), but here it is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                      imageFile = new File(
                              Environment
                                      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "goQuiz/profilePic.jpg"
                      );


                      Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);
                      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                      myVar = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

As of now, `myVar` stores the complete path of where the pic was saved to.

Basicly get a variable to save the `file.getAbsolutePath()` for you.